# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python

I don't get what's wrong with the code. It's working fine in cmd-line but subprocess can't handle it.

```
logs = subprocess.check_output("find -maxdepth 5 -name 'log.single'", shell = True).strip().split("\n")
```

Error

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'find -maxdepth 5 -name 'log.single'' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Using it from the shell it works just fine.

```
user@server:/mnt/x$ find -maxdepth 5 -name 'log.single'
./projects/X/Y/Target/log.single
./projects/X/Y1/Target/log.single
```

What makes me wonder even more is that the code works on lower levels but not this deep. If I go to /projects/X/ and change the maxdepth to 3 it works fine.

Comment: can you try `logs = subprocess.check_output(["find","-maxdepth","5","-name","log.single"]).strip().split("\n")` instead?

Comment: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['find', '-maxdepth', '5', '-name', 'log\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8b.single']' returned non-zero exit status 1 looks like the dot is messing up with the code but not in shell?

Comment: your dot is not really a dot, then. Can you remove it and type an actual dot?

Comment: There were some folders where the script couldn't enter but using find from the shell wasn't effected this issue. Running the code as a root worked. Thanks for your help anyway.